# Enantiomers or Identical Compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I don't know why my solutions manual says these are enantiomers:

[image]

The Fisher projections I drew suggest that these are identical compounds.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions manual is correct, they are enantiomers.  The compound on the left is (R)-2-chloro-(S)-3-butanol and the compound on the right is (S)-2-chloro-(R)-3-butanol.  Try to use the "R\S" nomenclature system on the 2 chiral carbons, that should help figuring out whether they are identical [(R,R and R,R), (S,S and S,S), (R,S and R,S), (S,R and S,R)] enantiomers [(R,R and S,S), (R,S and S,R), (S,R and R,S)] or diastereomers [(R,R and R,S), (R,R and S,R), (S,S and S,R), (S,S and R,S)].

Comment: Did I draw the Fischer projections wrong?

Comment: Yes, I believe the chlorine should be on the "inside" and the hydroxyl on the "outside" in the drawing on the left.

Comment: Hm, that suggests that I was looking at the molecule incorrectly when drawing the Fischer projections. From which perspective should I look at the molecules?

Comment: For me, it is easier to draw and understand Newman projections rather than Fisher projections.  I know Newman projections have been discussed previously in your posts, but have you tried them?

Comment: I think my issue was not keeping track of the carbons in the Fischer projections. If I suppose the carbon with the hydroxyl group as c2 and the other carbon with the chlorine is c3 (I don't know the actual numbering; nomenclature of alcohols has not been introduced) the the Fischer projections start making sense.

Comment: In the 3-dimensional views of the question, the 4 carbons are arranged in a trans (anti) conformation.  To draw the Fischer projection you should mentally rotate C-C bonds to all be in the cis (syn) conformation.

Comment: @ron but aren't RS and SR optically inactive? So shouldn't they be identical rather than enantiomers?

Answer (score 2):

In the following figure, everything on the left is identical and everything on the right is identical.

[image]

See [this page](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Chirality/Fischer_Projections) for how to draw Fischer Projections.